# AWS permissions - do we need to set permissions on both Lambda and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, permissions, aws-cloudformation

When we want a Lamdba function to be able to access an s3 bucket, for example:

```
actions: ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:DeleteObject"]
```

Is is enough to add the S3 bucket ARN and actions to the IAM policy statement on the Lambda or do we need to add any grant permissions onto the bucket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's enough to attach the policy to the Lambda role.

Example of policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "ExampleStmt",
      "Action": [
        ["s3:ListBucket", "s3:GetObject", "s3:PutObject", "s3:DeleteObject"]
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::AWSDOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Lambda is in the same account as the S3 bucket you can add this to the IAM role of the Lambda.

If it is in a **seperate account** you will need to add the IAM role Arn of the Lambda function as a Principal in the bucket policy, then add the permissions to the Lambdas IAM role.